# Dotnetnuke URL link not working

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

In dotnetnuke you can create a page to be linked in the menu by creating the page then under page setting in the "Links" section setting "URL". I have a site using DNN6 where these links were working before but I had to update the URL on two of them in the setting. I know the URL's are good, one is even a previously linked URL for that page that worked before. Now when you click on any that you update it does nothing. Setting "Permanent Redirect" or "open link in new browser window" in the same section on or off does not seem to have any effect. And of course because it is in the menu bar of dotnetnuke you can't see it on "view source" to see if the a tag is malformed or fix it if it was.

Has anyone else had this issue? I can't seem to find anything on Google. Is there any solution that could help? I really need to get this site fixed for this customer. Is there any support from DNN? When I go to get support to dotnetnuke I am directed to make a login to use their "Evoq" support then told I am not a Dotnetnuke customer (even though we use them for multiple sites) so I can't get support and the link to the "Customer Success Network" if you are a customer who is still getting that message just directs me back to the same message.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the link that appears in the menu, is the link formed correctly?  If so, it's possible that your page has javascript errors that break the page.  Use your browser's developer tools to check for that.

If you check the "open link in new browser window" you'll need to check that the link includes at target="_blank" attribute.  If it doesn't, the problem is with your menu's template.  Assuming that you are using the DDR menu, you'll want to check the DDR github site for updated templates.  They were updated earlier this year and might not have been included in your update version.  Just download them and copy over the existing templates and you should be fine.

The Evoq support that you mentioned is only for those who have purchased Evoq licenses.  I assume that you are using the Community Edition of DNN, and that doesn't include support.  There are, though, a number of organizations that do provide paid support for DNN.